# Best way to achieve offline folder sync in Android?

Tags: sync, cloud

The Google Drive client for desktop platforms allows to Make Available Offline any folder you want, usually inside a virtual drive (e.g. `G:/myFolders/syncedFolder` in Windows).

How can I achieve the same offline folder sync in Android devices?

I've tried 3rd party software that does it, but it's too buggy to use with important files (it accidentally deleted my data once).

Comment: As commented before, you can't. You can download any file using the app and save it to the local storage provided you have enough, of course.

Comment: By "offline sync", do you mean synchronizing folders between your Android device and your computer? Because "offline sync" using a cloud is hardly feasible ;) If I guessed right, what OS must be supported on your computer? Reading between the lines, most likely Windows – but would other OSes also be acceptable? Also, if it comes to (3rd party) software needed, any restrictions concerning pricing and license? Further it would help if you mentioned what you tried already, so we don't recommend something which you already know doesn't work for you.

Comment: @izzy - I tried some paid apps available at Google Play and found none suitable. I don't have any requirement or restriction, I don't care about the OS, it can be Mac or Linux, too. The apps I've tried were doing just that, copying some folder from the cloud and updating it with new content when they detect changes (new files, deletions, etc.) in the android-synced folder... I will try some DIY solution with termux and rclone/rsync in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks, that sheds some light. Then maybe I misunderstood what you mean by "offline": You want to sync files from some cloud storage for offline use then? If that's the case, maybe Tacit's FolderSync could be an option (they have a "free" testing version available if you want to give that a try).